# Using ASP.NET not able to Launch Outlook for booking appointment

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

Hi guys i am facing issue in Appointment booking using asp.net this error message is coming (E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005): Access denied) i am trying to open Outlook and send appointment on click.

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please provide some evidence of your work. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Office applications in an ASP.NET environment. This is not supported and will often not work as expected. That is why you get such error messages. Read [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

What you should do is use the Exchange Web Service (EWS) to [make an appointment instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx).